# How to keep the state when changing hash manually from the address bar?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to keep the state of the page when the hash is manually changed from the address bar.

The code is very simple, there are 2 routes.
The first route has a button that adds a random text to the state.
The second route shows the text in the state.

Strangely, when the Console is open ( `Ctrl+Shift+I` or `Ctrl+Shift+J` ) while changing the hash manually, the state is kept untouched. (expected behaviour)
I didn't type anything to the Console. I just opened it.

When I close the Console and change the hash manually, then the state is lost. (actual behaviour)

I know there are ways to store it at localStorage for example, but I'm trying to avoid it at the moment.

I actually am trying to understand how it worked as expected just because the Console were open.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because the hash of a url can't be updated manually (ie in the url bar) without reloading the page. When you change the hash via the console, you are changing it programmatically with js (not manually), which is the only way to alter the hash without reloading the page. When you type the hash into the url bar and hit enter, the page reloads, which means your app reloads and your state is reset.

Comment: I didn't type anything to the console. I just opened it. Then I changed the hash from the address bar manually and it worked as expected.

Comment: And yes, you can update the hash without reloading the page.